# Override Background Color

Tags: html, css

Let's say my body is this in my HTML File:

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

And this is my CSS-File:

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#F6F6F1;
}

body {
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

Why does the background-color in the `*` rule override the background-color in the `div` rule? Isn't the `div` rule more specific? If I put the background-color from the `*` rule to the `body` rule it works as I expected.

Comment: you don't have anything in the divs so they show up empty.

Comment: The "header" div isn't empty...

Comment: @Veve No, but since `margin` and `padding` are `0` throughout, it's *completely* filled by the `h1`, which gets the `*` `background-color` property.

Comment: @Paul Roub thanks for the explaination!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top div is completely filled in by the `h1`, which has the `*` background applied. The lower div is empty, so there's no background to fill.

Add content to the lower div to see its background:

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#F6F6F1;
}

body {
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
<div id="content">foo
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The background-color isnt overwritten.

You have 2 problems here:

1) Empty divs without given height and width are collapsing and therefore not rendered.

2) Your h1 does have `background-color:#F6F6F1` and does therefore overlap the div's background.

See this fiddle (transparent background on h1, red background on div's):
http://jsfiddle.net/ammxmckz/

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the universal selector is being applied to all elements, including the header `<h1>` element. So while the header div does get a different background, the `<h1>` header is covering it up.

For example, throw some margin on the header and you'll see the div's background peeking out from behind it:

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#F6F6F1;
}

body {
    width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div {
    background-color:#F00;
}

h1 {
    margin-left:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
     <h1>Hello!</h1>

</div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not overridden. However,

- `#content` and `#footer` are empty, so you can't see their background.
- `#header` has a red background color. However, its content is a `h1` element, which overlaps `#header`'s background. And `h1` has a `#F6F6F1` background color.

Answer (score 0):

The "universal" selector is a property of danger and should be kept clear of **any** CSS declarations that directly involve styling, ala `background-color`. The only use-case of today that's progressively using the universal selector is for declarations such as `box-sizing`.

The answer is obvious though. Wherever you apply background-color, it will be hidden by any element sat on top of it. That's the pure dangers of using global selectors.

A more helpful tip to finish this would be not to use the universal, or "global" selector for **any** UI styling. It's dangerous, dirty, muddy and worst of all, **scary**. Think of it as Freddie Krueger. Stay away from it. ;)